# android layout not refreshing

Tags: android, android-layout

My application does not want to refresh the view you see when I use `invalidate()` on either of my layouts, nor if I use `this.invalidate()`. I have used `.removeAllViews()` to remove the views from the target Layout and have tried using invalidate and that is not working either.

Is there another way to refresh the screen so that it shows an up to date image. The image users would see is a group of editTexts and labels depicting what information is needed and then this is all removed and then the screen should refresh to then not show it any more.

If any further information is required please ask, THIS IS URGENT!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where are you calling invalidate from? Pleas post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invalidate will force Android to update when onDraw is called again. You could try calling `onDraw(Canvas)` yourself, as it seems it's not getting called automatically.

Alternatively, you could create another layout file, and just change the layout of the view by using
   `setContentView(R.layout.newlayout)`

Comment: This is something I have not tried and have forgotten about, I will give it a go thanks. Also for the contextview that would not work as the layout I am trying to refresh is a child of the maincontext view.

Comment: I am unsure of how it would affect the layout of the app if I changed it. Sorry for dual messages I pressed enter by accident

Comment: Not yet ran into other problems I will try this when I fix the other problems. I am close to fixing them just have to fully define a few things.

Comment: OK well I have cleared many problems now, but the layout still does not wish to be refreshed or redrawn. Could you explain how to use the onDraw because I have looked around on-line and do not understand how they explain to do this.

Comment: That is weird. You could try overriding onDraw(Canvas) and checking if it's being called when you invalidate it?

Another way you could try refreshing is getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();

What I said earlier about calling onDraw yourself should not be necessary and is not advised. Something is simply wrong. Are you creating any layout objects in the code of the activity itself, or are they all created from the layout XML?

Comment: The layouts are being coded in Java form. I will give this new way a go. I have fixed a few more crashes since then but the visual components still don't want to pop up when I am changing between pages. The thing which worked e.g. the labels and button are re-drawn are not re-drawing any-more, I think ill try back trace the code to see why it stopped redrawing.